# Plot relative frequencies with dodged bar plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, frequency

can anybody answer how I can plot a bar-plot which maps a numeric x-variable to its relative frequency grouped by a factor in ggplot2? The important thing is:
The relative frequencies should be calculated as **groupwise** frequencies within x-values belonging to one factor. Now they are calculated as x-values relative to the **total** number of x-values.

To illustrates it, an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <-data.frame(x=runif(100,0:1), f=sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE))
data$f <-factor(data$f)
p <-ggplot(data, aes(x, colour=f, fill=f, group=f)) +
    xlim(0,1) +
    scale_y_continuous('Relative Frequency', formatter='percent') # or labels=percent
```

Let us plot them facetted. Then the y-axis shows that the proportions are calculated groupwise. I used this code:

```
p + stat_bin(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), position='dodge', binwidth=0.2) +         facet_grid(~f)
```

Let us plot them dodged. The y-axis shows that the proportions refer to the whole dataset. Here, I used the following code:

```
p + stat_bin(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), position='dodge', binwidth=0.2)
```

I aim at creating a plot like the second with the frequencies of the variable per group on the y-axis.

Thank a lot for your help in advance!
Jana

Comment: Your first graph is NOT giving per-facet proportions. You will need to pre-summarize the data and then pass it to ggplot.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem as yours and I figured it out: instead of plotting `..count../sum(..count..)`, plot `..density..*your_binwidth`
Indeed, the `..density..` variable created by the bin stat is basically equal to proportion/bindwidth.
Your code becomes:

```
p + stat_bin(aes(y=..density..*0.2), position='dodge', binwidth=0.2)
```

Comment: -1; Except this answer isn't quite right: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655648/how-can-i-plot-the-relative-proportions-of-two-groups-using-a-fill-aesthetic-in for the correct solution.