# ggplot2 - Multi-group histogram with in-group proportions rather than frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three cohorts of students identified by an `ExperimentCohort` factor. For each student, I have a `LetterGrade`, also a factor. I'd like to plot a histogram-like bar graph of `LetterGrade` for each `ExperimentCohort`. Using

```
ggplot(df, alpha = 0.2, 
       aes(x = LetterGrade, group = ExperimentCohort, fill = ExperimentCohort))                                                                                                                                                       
  + geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

gets me very close, but the three `ExperimentCohorts` don't have the same number of students. To compare these on a more even field, I'd like the y-axis to be the in-cohort proportion of each letter-grade. So far, short of calculating this proportion and putting it in a separate dataframe before plotting, I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Every solution to a similar question on SO and elsewhere involves `aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..))`, but sum(..count..) is executed across the whole dataframe rather than within each cohort. Anyone got a suggestion? Here's code to create an example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:60, 
        LetterGrade = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 60, replace = T),
        ExperimentCohort = sample(c("One", "Two", "Three"), 60, replace = T))
```

Thanks.

Comment: The title deals with histograms, not barplots

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Wrong solution

You can use `stat_bin()` and `y=..density..` to get percentages in each group.

```
ggplot(df, alpha = 0.2,
      aes(x = LetterGrade, group = ExperimentCohort, fill = ExperimentCohort))+
      stat_bin(aes(y=..density..), position='dodge')
```

### UPDATE - correct solution

As pointed out by @rpierce `y=..density..` will calculate density values for each group not the percentages (they are not the same).

To get the correct solution with percentages one way is to calculate them before plotting. For this used function `ddply()` from library `plyr`. In each `ExperimentCohort` calculated proportions using functions `prop.table()` and `table()` and saved them as `prop`. With `names()` and `table()` got back `LetterGrade`.

```
df.new<-ddply(df,.(ExperimentCohort),summarise,
              prop=prop.table(table(LetterGrade)),
              LetterGrade=names(table(LetterGrade)))

 head(df.new)
  ExperimentCohort       prop LetterGrade
1              One 0.21739130           A
2              One 0.08695652           B
3              One 0.13043478           C
4              One 0.13043478           D
5              One 0.30434783           E
6              One 0.13043478           F
```

Now use this new data frame for plotting. As proportions are already calculated - provided them as `y` values and added `stat="identity"` inside the `geom_bar`.

```
ggplot(df.new,aes(LetterGrade,prop,fill=ExperimentCohort))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position='dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks a lot... don't know how I failed to find this answer elsewhere. Do you know what it is about `..count..` that behaves this way while `..density..` does not? Or maybe it's endemic to the difference between `geom_bar` and `stat_bin`?

Comment: stat_bin function is applied to each group separately

Comment: Except this answer isn't quite right: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655648/how-can-i-plot-the-relative-proportions-of-two-groups-using-a-fill-aesthetic-in for the correct solution.

Comment: @rpierce Corrected my answer.

Comment: (+1) I tried this recently, and got most ways home, but needed to wrap this `prop=prop.table(table(LetterGrade))` in a call to `as.numeric`, so, `prop=as.numeric(prop.table(table(LetterGrade)))`.

Comment: This is not an histogram, it's a _barplot_

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this by creating a `weight` column that sums to 1 for each group:

```
ggplot(df %>%
         group_by(ExperimentCohort) %>%
         mutate(weight = 1 / n()),
       aes(x = LetterGrade, fill = ExperimentCohort)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(weight = weight), stat = 'count', position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: For me the `stat="count"` code generated some issues with `stat_count`. Removing that will work.

Comment: It does not seem to display the percentages  by group

Answer (score 0):

I recently attempted this and received an error calling ddply: `Column prop must be length 1 (a summary value), not 6`. Spent some time with ddply but couldn't quite get the solution to work so I offer up an alternative (note this still makes use of `plyr`):

```
df.new <- df2 %>% 
    group_by(ExperimentCohort,LetterGrade) %>% 
    summarise (n = n()) %>%
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

Then you can plot it just as @didzis-elferts mentioned:

```
ggplot(df.new,aes(LetterGrade,freq,fill=ExperimentCohort))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position='dodge')
```

Comment: could you explain the mutate step? why is sum(n) only within experimentcohort.  I would have expected sum(n) to be for whole data frame - seems magic!

Comment: If we had wanted `sum(n)` to be calculated over the whole data frame we would need to call `ungroup()` within the pipe before the mutate call. Note you can check the grouping by using `grouping(df.new)`, and that the `summarise` call will 'ungroup' the last grouping variable.

Comment: For example, add a column to the data frame:

`df <- data.frame(ID = 1:60,LetterGrade = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 60, replace = T),ExperimentCohort = sample(c("One", "Two", "Three"), 60, replace = T), test = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 60, replace = T))`

Then compare the output from:

`df %>%  group_by(ExperimentCohort,LetterGrade,test) %>% summarise (n = n()) %>% group_vars()`

 with:

`df %>% group_by(ExperimentCohort,LetterGrade,test) %>% group_vars()`

Comment: This is why the `mutate(freq = n / sum(n))` calculates the sum over the ExperimentCohort group and no longer over the LetterGrade group as well. Hope that helps clear it up!

Comment: The question is for histograms, not barplots